# OpenSSL WinINET client

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, ssl, openssl, wininet

I have a working client and a server which, once finished would have a valid SSL certificate.

At the moment, for the mean of testing, I'm just disabling the need of SSL verification in the client by adding the flags `INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID` and `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA` like this:

```
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnection,
           "GET","index.html",
           NULL,NULL,NULL,
           INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD|
           INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT
           #ifdef  __HTTPS__
           | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE |INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID|SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA
           #endif
           ,
           dwContext);
```

I got this to work perfectly on my laptop. Now I'm trying to use it on my PC. same code exactly. copied and pasted the files (both Visual Studio Professional 2008), now I'm getting `12045` error. which means `Invalid Certificate Authority`

I tried disabling Windows Firewall, didn't work. both computer connected to the same router

Any ideas what can cause this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Basically what happens is the same as described [here by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825828), only this article is for `Windows CE`

Comment: _"copied and pasted the files"_ - what files? Is `__HTTPS__` defined in the client PC's project?

Comment: At the moment it's a single source file within a VS project.
Yes, `__HTTPS__` is defined. I saw this now https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.winhttp/mr6mSt7SFYg but don't know if it has anything to do with it, I'm pretty new to the whole WinAPI thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q182888/en-US) help?

> If a server SSL certificate is issued by unknown or invalid certificate authority WinInet HttpSendRequest API or MFC CInternetFile::SendRequest will fail with error 12045 (ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_CA).

I think you should call `InternetSetOption()` on the request, before issuing it, like this, because the [`HttpOpenRequest()` flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do not specify `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA`:

```
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnection,...

#ifdef  __HTTPS__
    DWORD dwFlags;
    DWORD dwBuffLen = sizeof(dwFlags);
    InternetQueryOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, (LPVOID)&dwFlags, &dwBuffLen);

    dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;

    InternetSetOption (hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwFlags, sizeof (dwFlags));
#endif

HttpSendRequest(hRequest,...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm now getting error `12057` which is `ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_CERT_REV_FAILED`. Don't know what it means, but if I'm currently running from the laptop, it still works from there, so no server errors

Comment: As suggested here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.wininet/vVHnFoWZ8no I've added `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION` to your code. now it works. Thanks!

Comment: _"but if I'm currently running from the laptop"_ - did you generate and/or trust the server certificate on the laptop? That would explain you not getting the errors on that machine. Anyway, certificate revocation check is [disabled by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384266(v=vs.85).aspx). Edit: nice you solved it! :-)

Comment: I don't recall ever trusting the certificate on either computer. But at least it's running now. Hopefully once we'll move to a trusted certificate there won't be any issues. Thanks a lot!